# Do I have to set up applicationHost.config manually?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, webserver, iis-express

There is a file 'applicationHost.config' in "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config".

I found a piece of code

```
<sites>
        <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <application path="/OrionServices" applicationPool="ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\source\WebAdminOrion\OrionServices" />
            </application>
            <application path="/VendorServices" applicationPool="ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\source\WebAdminOrion\VendorServices" />
            </application>
            <application path="/WebAdminOrion" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\source\WebAdminOrion\WebAdminOrion" />
            </application>
            <application path="/WebAdminMobile">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\source\WebAdminOrion\WebAdminMobile" />
            </application>
```

I don't know whether these were created by machine itself or manually. The reason that I asked is there is only one site in it, which is "Default Web Site" id="1". I didn't create it.

I used Visual Studio 2012 to debug an asp.net mvc project(IIS Express of course) in my flash driver "H", there is no any information of it in the applicationHost.config.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually update applicationhost.config file if you wish to. Be sure to back it up.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig

Also, you want to make sure you refer to correct file: http://www.cosnetics.co.uk/articles/cannot-manually-edit-applicationhost.config/